# windowing function avg in Hive with - over (order by colName)

Tags: hive, windowing

i'm trying to understand how windowing function avg works, and somehow it seems to not be working as i expect.

here is the dataset :

> ```
> select * from winsales;
> +-------------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--+
> | winsales.salesid  | winsales.dateid  | winsales.sellerid  | winsales.buyerid  | winsales.qty  | winsales.qty_shipped  |
> +-------------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--+
> | 30001             | NULL             | 3                  | b                 | 10            | 10                    |
> | 10001             | NULL             | 1                  | c                 | 10            | 10                    |
> | 10005             | NULL             | 1                  | a                 | 30            | NULL                  |
> | 40001             | NULL             | 4                  | a                 | 40            | NULL                  |
> | 20001             | NULL             | 2                  | b                 | 20            | 20                    |
> | 40005             | NULL             | 4                  | a                 | 10            | 10                    |
> | 20002             | NULL             | 2                  | c                 | 20            | 20                    |
> | 30003             | NULL             | 3                  | b                 | 15            | NULL                  |
> | 30004             | NULL             | 3                  | b                 | 20            | NULL                  |
> | 30007             | NULL             | 3                  | c                 | 30            | NULL                  |
> | 30001             | NULL             | 3                  | b                 | 10            | 10                    |
> +-------------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--+
> ```

When i fire the following query ->

```
select salesid, sellerid, qty, avg(qty) over (order by sellerid) as avg_qty from winsales order by sellerid,salesid;
```

I get the following ->

```
 +----------+-----------+------+---------------------+--+
| salesid  | sellerid  | qty  |       avg_qty       |
+----------+-----------+------+---------------------+--+
| 10001    | 1         | 10   | 20.0                |
| 10005    | 1         | 30   | 20.0                |
| 20001    | 2         | 20   | 20.0                |
| 20002    | 2         | 20   | 20.0                |
| 30001    | 3         | 10   | 18.333333333333332  |
| 30001    | 3         | 10   | 18.333333333333332  |
| 30003    | 3         | 15   | 18.333333333333332  |
| 30004    | 3         | 20   | 18.333333333333332  |
| 30007    | 3         | 30   | 18.333333333333332  |
| 40001    | 4         | 40   | 19.545454545454547  |
| 40005    | 4         | 10   | 19.545454545454547  |
+----------+-----------+------+---------------------+--+
```

Question is - how is the avg(qty) being calculated.
Since i'm not using partition by, i would expect the avg(qty) to be the same for all rows.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have **same avg(qty)** to get for all rows then **remove** `order by sellerid` in over clause, then you are going to have **19.545454545454547** value for all the rows.

**Query to get same avg(qty) for all rows:**

```
hive> select salesid, sellerid, qty, avg(qty) over () as avg_qty from winsales order by sellerid,salesid;
```

If we include `order by sellerid` in **over clause** then you are getting cumulative avg is caluculated for each sellerid.
i.e. for

```
sellerid 1 you are having 2 records total 2 records with qty as 10,30 so avg would be 
     (10+30)/2.
sellerid 2 you are having 2 records total 4 records with qty as 20,20 so avg would be 
     (10+30+20+20)/4 = 20.0
sellerid 3 you are having 5 records total 9 records with qty as  so 10,10,15,20,30 avg would be 
(10+30+20+20+10+10+15+20+30)/9 = 18.333
sellerid 4 avg is 19.545454545454547
```

when we include over clause then this is an expected behavior from hive.